# Django - VueJS - Can't be null

Tags: python, django, vue.js, null, field

i work on a project with Django and VueJs. I have a problem with a field can't be null but i don't understand why.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Tache(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    echeance = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    sous_titre = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    fait = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="taches")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from taches.models import Tache


class TacheSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # echeance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    echeance = serializers.DateTimeField(format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tache
        exclude = ["updated_at"]

    def get_created_at(self, instance):
        return instance.created_at.strftime("%d" + "/" + "%m" + "/" + "%Y")

    # def get_echeance(self, instance):
    #     if instance.echeance != None:
    #         return instance.echeance.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

My problem "field can't be null are on "echeance" field.
You can see i have 4 lines in comments because => don't work so i do that : 
echeance = serializers.DateTimeField(format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
I think my problem come here...

Do you have any idea why "echeance" can't be null...?

Thank's

EDIT : I'have this error when i try to create a new "tache" by the user interface and the api django rest frameword. But i can create a new "tache" by the django admin... When i see the "tache" in the api, "echeance" = null.
I'm lost...

SOLUTION : I have change the model field of "echeance" to DateField. After i change in the serializer : echeance = models.DateField(format = "%d/%m/%Y", allow_null=True, required=False). I have just the date and not the time but it's work.

Comment: What actual traceback/exception are you getting?

Comment: This is console error : VM31718:1 PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/taches/dsfsdfqsdfsf-8r4teg/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: And the network error in french : {"echeance":["Ce champ ne peut être nul."]}  Trad: this field can't be null

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention allow_blank and allow_true

Try this

```
echeance = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)
```

Comment: I have this error when i launch the serv : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_blank'

Comment: only use allow_blank=True, allow_null=True for echeance don't use for other fields

Comment: Yeah, like that ? echeance = serializers.DateTimeField(format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)   This don't work for me...

Comment: ok try this `echeance = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)`

Comment: The creation works with your method but then you can't set a due date ("echeance"). And it's important to be able to set one ahah. Read_only = false don't work too